# Pattern matching using regex python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Here are the text examples :

- American Psychological Association. (2016). **Center for
  epidemiological studies depression (CESD)**. Retrieved December 7,
  2016, from American Psychological Association, http://www.apa.org/pi/
  about/publications/caregivers/practice-settings/
  assessment/tools/depression-scale.aspx
- Beattie, G.S. (2005, November). **Social Causes of Depression**.
  Retrieved May 31, 2017, from http://
  www.personalityresearch.org/papers/beattie.html

I want the Bold part of the text for which I tried:

```
/\)\.|\s[a-zA-Z]+\./
```

Here I look for ')' then '.' then 'space' and then text until '.'

Basically I want the **text between two Dots** as this is the title of paper which starts after either author or publication with year in brackets as mentioned in the example. But above `pattern` doesn't give what I want.

Can anyone help me why it is not working and what could be the other way to find text like these in my dataframe column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `Series.str.extract`:

```
\)\.\s+([^.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAk9re/1).

**Details**

- `\)\.` - `).` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a dot

In Pandas, you may use it like

```
df['res_col'] = df['orig_col'].str.extract(r'\)\.\s+([^.]+)', expand=False)
```

**Update as per comments**

A more specific regex that allows any known abbreviations is

```
[\d)]\.\s*((?:\ba\.k\.a\.|[^.])+)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAk9re/4). Details:

- `[\d)]` - either a digit or `)`
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `((?:\ba\.k\.a\.|[^.])+)` - Group 1: one or more occurrences of `a.k.a.` substring as a whole word or any char but a dot.

Comment: @It's_me Use `r'[\d)]\.\s*([^.]+)'`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAk9re/2).

Comment: is there any way we highlight text and it's regex form appear in the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAk9re/3)? I am asking for vice-versa

Comment: @It's_me No, it does not work like this. You may use various tools to build patterns, like http://buildregex.com/ (no affilation).

Comment: what if all the pattern doesn't match in single regex form for particular data?

Comment: @It's_me Then you should re-think your requirements. If you cannot formulate the requirements verbally in terms of text, you won't be able to write a regex. Remember that regex is text-driven.

Comment: how to exclude + include these 'a.k.a' in between text as pattern will break on finding first '.' ?

Comment: @It's_me [Like this](https://regex101.com/r/aAk9re/4): `[\d)]\.\s*((?:\ba\.k\.a\.|[^.])+)`.

Comment: @It's_me Please do not share images, share the text using regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?<=\)\.)[\w\s\(\)]*(?=\.)
```

- `(?<=\)\.)`  Is a look behind search to check if ")." is preceded by ).
- `[\w\s\(\)]*` To allow all words and white space characters and also ( and ) chracters.
- `(?=\.)` Is a look-ahead search to check for chracter .

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/5UVVKm/1)

[image]

Comment: First of all, there is no need for lookarounds, in Pandas, `extract` / `findall` allow easy access to capturing groups. But the `(?<=\)\.)[\w\s\(\)]*(?=\.)` won't match if there are hyphenated words in the string, and other "legal" punctuation. The whitelisting approach does not look appropriate for a requirement *match up to the next dot*.